# Jquery calendar multiple highlight colors

Tags: jquery, calendar

I have a couple problems in Jquery Calendar but I posted in different questions.

This question is about highlits two ranges of dates in different colors, blue for chosen dates in previous page and red for not available dates.

I achieve to set classes for those ranges, but the second style is not beeing aplied, this is my code:

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();

                for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
                    if($.inArray(y + '-' + (m+1) + '-' + d,disabledDays) != -1) {
                        //return [false];
                        return [true, 'dp-highlight', ''];
                    }

                }
                for (i = 0; i < chosenDays.length; i++) {
                    if($.inArray(y + '-' + (m+1) + '-' + d,chosenDays) != -1) {
                        //return [false];
                        return [true, 'dp-highlight2', ''];
                    }

                }
                return [true];
```

the default dp-highlight class is ok and the calendar highlights that class, but the one I created dp-highlight2 is being canceled according to firebug.

this is the style for both,

```
.dp-highlight .ui-state-default{background:#C00;color:#FFF}
.dp-highlight2 .ui-state-default {background:#2b93e9;color:#FFF}
```

What other style do I need to add or change for the style to be accepted?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

The function just return the only one value at once,so the second condition can't reach.

When you run over first condition. Then return value and finish this callback function.